# CakePHP3 how to use 2 default layout

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I work on cakePHP 3 Project and i want to use another default layout for Admin..

So in Login Action if it is Admin i will redirect it to dashboard admin wich should have another default layout..

```
  public function login()
    {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();

    if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
             if($user('role')=== 'admin')
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'dashboard']);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'home', 'controller' => 'pages']);
    }
}
```

But how to specify that the controller `admin` will use another default layout not only specify in action by using :

```
   //admin controller 
   public action dashboard(){
    $this->layout='default2';
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For change default layout add layout change in your `AppController` or  `AdminController` `beforeFilter method`.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');
}
```

For change individual layout

```
public function login()
{
   $this->viewBuilder()->layout('login');
}
```

Comment: How to apply this just for one controller not to all of them

Comment: @kh.tab add beforeFilter method in that controller

Answer (score 2):

Before CakePHP 3.1, you have to use the following:

`$this->layout = 'admin';`

After CakePHP 3.1, you have to use the following:

`$this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');`

Comment: how can i apply this for all action not only for one ?